# how to get the all messages in a topic from kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to get all the messages from beginning in a topic from server.

Ex:

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic testTopic --from-beginning

When using the above console command, I would like to able to get all messages in a topic from the beginning but I couldn't consume all the messages in a topic from beginning using java code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be to start a consumer and drain all the messages. Now I don't know how many partitions you have in your topic and whether you already have a an existing consumer group or not, but you have a few options:

Have a look at this API: https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

1) If you already have a consumer in the same consumer group, and still want to start consuming from the beginning, you should use the `seek` option listed in the API doc and set the offset to 0 for each consumer in the group. This would start consuming from the beginning.

2) Otherwise, you can start a few consumers in a new consumer group & you would not have to worry about seek.

PS: Please remember to provide more details about your setup in the future if you have more questions on Kafka. A lot of things depend on how you have configured your infrastructure & how you would prefer it to be and would thus vary from case to case.

Comment: For a new consumer group, you also need to set `auto.offset.reset = earliest`

Comment: Also, it would be good if you can specify the Kafka Version explicitly in your documentation answer. This is because there is a lot of difference in how consumer offsets are handled. Earlier it was the job of zookeeper (before 0.9) but now is handled by kafka topic  "__consumer_offset". I find many people getting confused because of things changing between versions.

Comment: I agree -- actually, SO Documentation supports an explicit "version" field, but it was disabled for me when I wrote the stuff, so I could not include the version :( Maybe I can set it, after the topic as reviewed and accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Manav

I got all the messages using below code as per your suggestion seek.
 
 TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
 List<TopicPartition> partitions = Arrays.asList(topicPartition);
 consumer.assign(partitions);     
 consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);

Answer (score 11):

You can get all messages using the following command:

```
cd Users/kv/kafka/bin

./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --topic topicName --from-beginning --max-messages 100
```

Answer (score 8):

```java
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
List<TopicPartition> partitions = Arrays.asList(topicPartition); 
consumer.assign(partitions);
consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the consumer group

> ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG - to new group id

and set

> AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG - earliest

sample code-

```
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "newID");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

Comment: this may helpful for development and testing, setting new group_id in production is not good practice right?