# How to read the entire Kafka topic, from beginning to end, without changing the group.id and without knowing about topic's partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am reading from Kafka topic, and I commit the read offsets.

Can I somehow, using the same group.id and without seeking on a particular partition as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926374/how-to-get-the-all-messages-in-a-topic-from-kafka-server), re-read the entire topic from beginning to end?

using Kafka 1.1
my pseudo code:

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
 { "group.id", "NCC1"},
 ...
 { "enable.auto.commit", "false"},
 { "default.topic.config", new Dictionary<string, object>
 {
  { "auto.offset.reset", "earliest" } 
 }
 }
};      

using (var consumer = new Consumer<string, string>(config, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8), new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
{
  consumer.Subscribe(new string[] { topic });
  consumer.OnMessage += (_, msg) =>
  {
    // DO SOMETHING
    onsumer.CommitAsync(msg);
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use kafka-consumer-group to reset offsets for the existing group ids.

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafkahost:port> --group <group_id> --topic <topic_name> 
--reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute
```

It will reset the offset for the given topic and group.id to the earliest.

You can see more options there:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling

Answer (score 1):

Kafka allows you to reset the offset for a particular topic and group id. This possibility of replay is actually one of the selling points of Kafka.

You can do it using the `kafka-streams-application-reset` commandline tool as [documented here](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html).

An alternative way is to use `kafka-consumer-groups` command line tool as described [in this blog](https://gist.github.com/marwei/cd40657c481f94ebe273ecc16601674b). The alternative way might be interesting if you are using Windows since the equivalent batch file for `kafka-streams-application-reset.sh` is not provided.

Obviously, you can move your offset backward as long as the events are still in the topic. Events already removed from the topic cannot be replayed.

**EDIT**

I think your question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670937/kafka-0-11-how-to-reset-offsets)